How to distinguish if change is from UI?
I have a spinbox event linked to the handler
self.spinBoxBalanceHours.valueChanged.connect(self.balanceChanged)

There is also programmatic change of the value
self.spinBoxBalanceHours.setValue(...)

How can I either determine that the change is made from UI or programmatically?
Alternatively, any way to set the value of spinbox without causing any event fired?

See: QObject.blockSignals or QSignalBlocker (in Python, the latter can be used as a context-manager).
